# Anyway to run Bitlocker without a key during a boot/reboot?

Tags: bitlocker

I recently have begun deploying new machines in my company and have been attempting to run Bitlocker on it. I insert the flash drive, save the key there, set default settings and rebooted. This was not an issue before until the flash drive I saved them into died on me. Now every flash drive I put in asks me which encryption mode I need, how much of my drive I want to encrypt etc. And if I remove the flash drive, it asks me for a key or to reinsert the flash drive back for it to boot properly.

Is there a setting where I can enable bitlocker and not have a boot/reboot ask me for a key every time? I been tinkering with the Group Policy but I have had no luck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I presume you have created a new key with the required recovery key?  Perhaps I am not understanding your question.  Is Windows asking you to erroneously encrypt every removable you attempt to mount?

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying back on this. Looks like I figured it out, I needed to go into the group policy of the PC and selectRequire additional authentication at start up" and allow everything but deselect "Allow Bitlocker without a compatible TPM(Requires a password or a startup key on a USB Flash Drive). Ive also come to find out that any custom build desktops wont allow it since theres no 'TPM chip' on it, and most laptops do. 

Now I have a question: Is it possible to enable that same GP (The "Require additional authentication at startup") affect any user who already has BL enabled?

Comment: Have you tried it on a test group of machines? Also, your question has now changed very substantially. You should edit it to focus on your current question, or you should answer this question and post another one with the new question.